# Using the py2neo driver, how can I create nodes from a list with the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, neo4j, cypher

I have successfully connected my neo4j database with the py2neo package. I am using jupyter notebook. I have a list that I need to create nodes with.

What do I put in `$name` part?

```
list = [a, b, c]
from py2neo import Database, Graph
db = Database("bolt://localhost:7687")
gr = Graph(password="password")

for name in list:
  gr.run("CREATE (:Person {name: $name})")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a **name** as a parameter to `gr.run` function.

```
for name in list:
  gr.run("CREATE (:Person {name: $name})", name=name)
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, I was missing the ", name=name" part in the gr.run!